# Error to print dist object in R to latex code (knitr, stargazer)

Tags: r, latex, distance, knitr, stargazer

I am trying to print a dist object in latex code using stargazer.

example

```
require(ape)
require(stargazer)

data(woodmouse)
dd<-dist.dna(woodmouse)

stargazer(dd)
Error in objects[[i]]$zelig.call : 
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Also when I try with xtable

```
xtable(dd)
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
método não aplicável para 'xtable' aplicado a um objeto de classe "dist"
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why knitr or latex is at issue.

Comment: This is more likely problem in handle with dist object in knitr than latex issue.

Comment: `dist` appears not coercible to any object stargazer/xtable are able to handle! You need to index `dd` to more simple objetcs like `data.frame` or `matrix`.

Comment: Yeah, I coerced to matrix and got just lower tri to print.  This works good. thanks